# How do you aim with a pistol during combat?

Tags: assassins-creed-unity

There is an optional objective in a main mission to get four headshots. However, I don't know how to aim with the pistol. When I'm not in combat I can aim by holding L1 and shooting with R2, but during combat pressing L1 does a quick shot and holding it doesn't make a difference.

How can you aim without doing a quick shot?

Comment: Have you tried leaving combat?
In previous installments you'd only be able to aim if you weren't focusing on anyone (thus "leaving" combat), and aim at that momment

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Aiming is initiated by the L1. In combat, it becomes the quick shot. There are no alternatives to aim.

Comment: @JeffMercado Yes, you're right. If you post it as an answer I can accept it. I ended up climbing onto a building and shooting from there to finish the objective.

Comment: Thanks @Oak too. That I can aim outside of combat I wrote in the question and Arno will automatically draw his weapon when an enemy gets close. So I'd have to run away and vanish to aim effectively. Maybe I remember it wrong, but I thought in some game before you could aim with enemies around you. I thought it must be possible here because of the objective to get headshots, but I didn't think of just climbing up a building to do so. :D

Comment: I haven't played Unity, but played a lot of the previous games, especially Brotherhood & Blackflag, and the trick was that try to stop the "fighting aiming" animation to the free running mode to get to manually aim, sorry if I can't help any further =(

Comment: @Oak, you right, you need to leave the combat to AIM